# Is the $=$ in the preorder $\geq$ identity or equivalence in the preorder?

Tags: notation, terminology, order-theory, equivalence-relations

**Question**

Is the $=$ in the preorder $\geq$ identity or equivalence in the preorder?

**Background**

By way of example, let $\geq$ be the preorder on the cyclic set $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$ having the chain $0,1,2,1\ldots$

There are two possible ways to break down and interpret the relation $a\geq b$:

1. We can write it as $a>b$ OR $a=b$ with equals meaning the identity relation.  So $1=1$ and $2=2$
2. We can write it as $a>b$ OR $a\sim b$ with similar meaning "equal in the preorder", i.e. $1\sim1$, $2\sim2$, AND $1\sim 2$.

Which does it mean?

Comment: If the preorder is $\ge$, then I would say that $\ge$ is the preorder. At best, you have to decide what $>$ is.

Comment: You shouldn't use $\wedge$ and $\vee$ for "and" and "or" when talking about preorders – they usually mean "meet" and "join" in this context.

Comment: Thanks @ZhenLin sorry if that was confusing - fixed.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path in my example 1, $>$ is no different to $\geq$, right?  Whereas in my example 2, $>$ could either be the same as $\geq$ or stronger, is that right? (or if in my example 2 I had written XOR then $>$ would be strictly stronger.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbol "$=$" in mathematics should always be reserved to denote actual equality. That is, the two objects on both sides are identical. This applies to the situation of preorders as well, so in your example $1\le 2$ and $2\le 1$ but still $1\neq 2$.

Comment: Thanks. I know entirely what you mean (and don't disagree) although FWIW I have a philosophical objection to the idea of *identity*, by which I mean that if two things are entirely equal in every respect, they're not two things, they're one. This may seem pedantic but *every* identity relation is an equivalence relation, defined by what aspects of identity we're willing to overlook to consider two different things equivalent. e.g. one three of $\color{red}{3}=\color{blue}{3}$ is red and the other blue, but $=$ is an equivalence relation which is happy to overlook that.

Comment: The nature of identity is generally governed by the domain of numbers we're operating in at the time, i.e. $\color{red}{3}=\color{blue}{3}$ are equal when projected down to the natural numbers - and I recognise that *that* is the sense of equality which you mean $=$ should be reserved for.  Anyway, I've gone off on a tangent.  Thanks for the answer, I had a misconception about thinking it meant *equivalent in the preorder* and your answer clears that up.

Comment: I guess you do mathematics based on ZF(C) set theory. There equality of sets is given by the extensionality axiom and every other object is encoded as a set. So "$=$" then always refers to equal encodings as sets, which is what I referred to as "identical". Glad I could help though ;-)